# Regex to match the first occurance starting from the end of the string

Tags: python, regex

How do you match the first occurance of `start`, starting from the end of the string? I have tried it with a negative lookahead but instead I get `start\nfoo\nmoo\nstart\nfoo\ndoo` as match

```
import re
pattern='(start[\s\S]*$)(?=$)'
string='start\nfoo\nmoo\nstart\nfoo\ndoo'
re.search(pattern, string)
```

expected match: `start\nfoo\ndoo`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this code:

```bash
string='start\nfoo\nmoo\nstart\nfoo\ndoo'
print (re.findall(r'(?s).*(\bstart\b.*)', string))
##> ['start\nfoo\ndoo']
```

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `(?s)`: Enable single line or DOTALL mode to make dot match line break as well
- `.*`: Match longest possible match including line breaks
- `(\bstart\b.*)`: Match word `start` and everything after that till end in capture group #1. `\b` are necessary to avoid it matching `restart` or `starting` words.

PS: Since `.*` is greedy in nature before `start` it consume longest possible string before matching last `start`

Comment: Thanks for the explaination. Made it much more clearer to me. One question, how would you go on about if the line breaks are important indicators for the pattern? It seems my example was bad but basically I am trying to match everything that follows after the last sentence in a string. Using (?s) to remove linebreaks makes it more difficult to do so. For example `\nThis is a sen-\ntence.\nThis is another sentence.\nConfusing.stuff\nLast\nsentence.\nString to be matched\nPart II\n`. In this case I would have looked for the last occurance of `\.\n`

Comment: If your input text contains line breaks then `(?s)` becomes important to match across the lines. Regarding your new pattern `re.findall(r'(?s)(\.\n.*)', string)` would just work fine. It will give `.\nThis is another sentence.\nConfusing.stuff\nLast\nsentence.\nString to be matched\nPart II\n` as matched group.